# Creating New Content Types - Parent- Child Sites

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type

In my site I am creating a new site and subsites. We have a main site that we want to collect the different Projects (parent) and have the subsites have the project information along with other webparts (Group Members)/Tasks Lists/. I went to the main site -->Site Actions-->Site Settings-->Galleries-->Site Content Types-->Create and created a content type 'Projects'. I am still learning my way through SharePoint and just want to make sure I have done this part correctly.

The Parent is 'List Content Types'/'Item' and the 'Existing group' is 'Custom Content Types' after I select OK the only column is 'Title' I can change to Project Name/Title.

My thought to doing this was to have the end user select the 'Project Name/Title' and then have this move them to the site of that specified project.? By instead of having an 'Item', have a 'Link'? I don't know what would be best. (Specs are below)

I was advised:

> I would like for it to be one site for each Project Charter.  The project charter home would have a list of all sub-sites; you would create a new Project Charter from a site template.
>
> Each Project Charter site should have all the information about the project visible on the main
> page of the site. Something like this:

[Image - is this possible?](http://www.flickr.com/photos/compgeekess/5787367001/)

To me this sounds like there are TWO pages. The main page has the Project Charter (the Parent) and the second page displays all the information for the specified Project the user is working with.

I have created a few different sites and selected different site options to configure what would be best. So far, I believe if the HOME site is only going to list the project names, the WIKI page would be best. Then for the site that will contain Project info, maybe use a 'Document Workspace' since on of the requirements, according to an image indicates the Group Members are shown on the site.

Comment: Ok, better yet how do I create a list of sub-sites that a user can select from to be taken to a desired site/page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did exactly this just recently

1. Create your new content type
2. on the SubSites, the main list uses that content type
3. Make a site template out of you finished subsite. All future creations use that saite template
4. On the Parent site, use a Content Query web part. You will be able to tell it what Content type to read from all of its subsites.
5. So, on the main page of the Parent, your CQWP will show a list of all List Items created with that Content Type. Click the displayed link, and you go directly to that list item in the SubSite.

One issue: The Content Query Web PArt only shows one field (Title) by default, but that is changeable by editing the xslt.

Comment: Ok, I did do some of this earlier, as I was looking through 'SharePoint 2010 for Dummies'. I created a content type 'Project' and have its parent Link. When I go to the parent site I can add a name for a new project, select the name and then the URL takes me to the child. The only thing I noticed, doing it this way is a pop-up opens and shows the URL. At the moment I only have 'Project Title' as a column. Now I'm having issues creating the template. Another question already posted. :) Thank You.

Comment: Also, whatever fields you create as part of the new Content Type are exposed to the CQWP properties, and as such are sortable/filterable within the CQWP.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently created a "Project Center" with a main site collection as the portal and each project in the company having it's own subsite.

To access each of the project sites, I have a custom list running on the main site and use audience targeting on the list so people can only see projects they are involved with. These links are displayed on the site collections main page, no need for two separate pages unless you are specifically asked to do it that way.

To make it look less bland, the main page on the Project Center displays a dynamically created set of promotional tiles for each of the sites the user has access to. You can use something like [SPJS-Tiles](http://spjsblog.com/2013/11/13/sharepoint-2013-style-tiles/) for this.